# Twitter Typeahead Get Dataset

Tags: twitter-typeahead

I have a problem about Twitter typeahead. This is my first work with it, so this post may be too easy to solve but I want some help.
When I run the codes, cannot see any data in input. However when I alert my data, I can see the Json file. This make me confused. What is the reason and solution?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#typeahead_example_3').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'all-banks',
        display: 'value',
        source: function () {
            jQuery.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                url: "/supplier/suppliercompany/getallbanks",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    return data;
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                }
            })
        },
        templates: {
            empty: [
              '<div class="empty-message">',
                'unable to find any Best Picture winners that match the current query',
              '</div>'
            ].join('\n'),
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<div><strong>{{BankName}}</strong></div>')
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is my Html:

```
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Custom Template</label>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon">
   <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
   </span>
   <input type="text" id="typeahead_example_3" name="typeahead_example_3" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <p class="help-block">
   Uses a precompiled template to customize look of suggestion.</code>
   </p>
   </div>
   </div>
```